# Can I check if the form is dirty in a custom process or with JavaScript?

Tags: orbeon

I have a custom process tied to a button, defined as follows:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send-to-myservice.*.*">
    set-data-status(status="safe")
    then send(
              uri="http://localhost:8080/myservice",
              content="xml",
              replace="none",
              prune="true"
             )
    then success-message(message="Save Successful")
    then navigate(uri="javascript:window.MY_NAMESPACE.orbeonPostSave()")
    recover error-message(message="Save Failed")
</property>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.resource.*.*.en.buttons.send-to-myservice" value="Save"/>
```

I would like to perform the `send` operation only if the form is dirty. Can I change this process to conditionally `send` only if clean?

I am using the proxy portlet and actually hiding the Orbeon button. I have my own custom buttons that simulate clicking on the Orbeon button using JavaScript. Is there a JavaScript function I can call to check the data-status? That would be just as good or maybe better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the "opposite" of `set-data-status()`, i.e. something to read the data status. Right now, you would have to do this using XPath, with something like:

```
if ("xxf:instance('fr-persistence-instance')/data-status = 'dirty'")
then send(…)
else nop
```

And, obviously, you'd have to do this before you run `set-data-status(status="safe")`, otherwise the test will always fail.

Comment: We do need a standard function for this. We already suggest `fr:form-data-saved()` in [issue #1095](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1095).

Comment: Yes, I added a +1 on that issue.

Comment: Thanks, @avernet. That works perfectly. I wasn't sure about the syntax for including multiple executions under the `then` clause of the `if` but guessed right that I just needed to wrap it with parentheses. That is, `if (...) then (set-data-status(status="safe") then send(...)) else nop then navigate(...) recover ...`.

Comment: @awilkinson, perfect. Indeed, you can use parenthesis for this. There is more about this, and the general syntax on the page about the [process syntax](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/syntax.html).